# (MySQL) Does replication have a bin-log?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, mysqlbinlog

I make replication using aws-rds, and set bin-log and server-id property in parameter group(like my.cnf).
and type below query
`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin';`
but result is log_bin   OFF

Does replication have a bin-log??
How can I set bin-log to replication db?

Comment: Check the status of the instance in the RDS console.  It may show "pending-reboot," which means your parameter group changes have not been applied.  Verify that the correct parameter group is associated with the instance.  What do you see?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I can see in-sync in parameter group, and I reboot many times...

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001';

On slave to set log bin.

reference : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/change-master-to.html

Comment: I'm aws-rds user...
It caused error,
message: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation...
I set log_bin_trust_function_creators to 1

Comment: You need to give replication access to slave.
To do that you have to give,
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'slave_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

On master.